# Best approach to paging database data in ASP.Net (SQL Database VS Webserver)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, session-variables

I have already implemented two pretty fast ways of paging a large MS SQL Server database table which contains at least `1,000,000` records, but have failed to determine the pros and cons of either method, advise on either would be greatly appreciated:

The first is to run the SQL query and return only the Primary Key values of the filtered records, specifying a TOP clause of maybe 100-1000.  These can then be placed into a session variable on the web server and paged through accordingly by supplying a subset of Primary Key values back to the server.

One positive to this is the filtering of the records only occurs once when the user initially performs the search and secondly it gives the ability to page through the entire record set one item at a time if needs be, such as in previews of upcoming records, etc.  This method also provides some benefits with regards to further filtering already filtered records, as filterable options can be determined by supplying the list of Primary Key values back to the SQL Server - such as common attributes, title, directors, etc.

The second option is to perform both the filtering and paging via SQL Server, supplying variables such as 'records per page' and 'page number', etc .

The benefit to this is that there is no need to clog up the web server with user sessions that size wise will undoubtedly be at least 1000+ bytes each, which will only cause problems in the long run as the number of web site users increases.  In contrast, the down sides are ultimately what I've listed as being the positives for the first option, such as the lack of the ability to determine filtering options for the whole records set having only a single page or subset of Primary Key values to work with on the web server.

What are everyone's thoughts given the above, especially with regards to storing the Primary Key values for the results in a session variable, memory, alternate options, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the kind of person who thinks that Database time is more valuable than Webserver time. But that's my approach.
In your case, how do you retrieve the data? Do you use DataSet/DataTables or do you use Strong typed containers? Why not using linq or another filtering technique in the web server side or even the client Side? (You can display all the record to the user and use javascript to filter).

Comment: I agree with the premise "the db is usually the bottleneck".  You can always add more webservers to a farm to hit the same db.

Comment: or more RAM to current web servers.

Comment: The data is mostly retrieved via basic CRUD functions which utilize SqlClient classes, returned in XML format and then de-serialized into strongly typed objects - although this is only done when returning complex objects with child/parent relationships.

The process of data retrieval is pretty good and returns data from the primary query extremely quickly, my main concern would be the clogging up of the servers memory with countless session variables and then the need to re-implement later down the line.

Comment: Try to save the data in the session in the web server in case it need to be retrieve from cached. Also do the paging, filtering and sorting and stuff in the client using js (maybe you can use html5 storage capabilities). So with this your are hitting your web server memory but all the processing related to the manipulation of the data is happening in the client.